# Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, gmail

Не работает MailSender

MailSender.java

```
@Service
public class MailSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message){
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mailMessage.setFrom(username);
        mailMessage.setTo(emailTo);
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(message);

        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }

}
```

Mailconfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class Mailconfig {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${mail.debug}")
    private String debug;

    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth}")
    private String auth;

    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
    private String enable;


    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getEmailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender =   new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);
        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", enable);


        return  mailSender;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mymail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=mypass
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.debug=true
```

Ошибка

```
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2021-06-14 11:11:34.425 ERROR 8164 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate); message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)] with root cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается надо просто указать версию протокола, странно что без этого не работает.

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```